# Bypassing Python's private attributes inadvertently

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, encapsulation

I managed to bypass the setter using the following code :

```
t = TrajetGPS()

# will call t.getPoints(), which will return the list by reference
# we can then modify it at will, bypassing the setter
points = t.points 
points.append(PointGPS(0, 0, 0))
points.append(PointGPS(1, 1, 1))


print(t) # will show : Points : (0, 0, 0) (1, 1, 1)
```

*The `TrajetGPS()` is defined as a simple class containing a list of `PointGPS` defined with `points = property(getPoints, setPoints)` and `PointGPS()` contains 3 coordinates (latitude, longitude, altitude). But all this doesn't matter here.*

**Is it normal I can bypass the setter without a warning ?**

Python is designed to be beginner-friendly, but this doesn't seem very friendly as it can be very quick to insert malformed data into the list (without knowing !).

Comment: Python can't avoid you shooting your own foot without tying your arms behind your back, which wouldn't be productive either. If you want to ensure immutability, return an immutable data structure from your property, or return a copy of the list.

Comment: It's the class that decides to return its private member, not the caller.

Comment: Assigning a value to an attribute and mutating the value of an attribute are two different things. A setter can prevent you from doing the former, but not the latter - because you're not *setting* the attribute, you're *modifying* it.

Comment: Very important to note, *Python doesn't have private attributes*. As the answers have notes, this has nothing to do with "bypassing a setter". Even in languages like Java with strongly enforeced private access modifiers, if your attribute is an object that you mutate then that change will be seen in the instance that attribute belongs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually NOT "bypassing the setter" - the setter is invoked when your trying to set `t.points` (ie: `t.points = []`), not when you are *mutating* the list returned by the setter.

If you don't want client code to mutate the list, either return some immutable structure (which will make clear that it's not supposed to be changed) or at least return a copy of the list (which will then still be mutable, but the modification wont affect the original list - note that this might suprise your code users).

NB : in your code snippet there is this comment:

> which will return the list by reference

If you hope to get anything done in Python, stop thinking in terms of some other language and understand how Python works instead. There's is nothing like "by reference" or "by value" in Python, only names and objects. Your getter doesn't "return the list by reference", it returns the list, period. I strongly suggest your [read this reference article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (yeah, lame pun, sorry) for more on Python's concepts of names and objects.

Answer (score 3):

Python is not specially beginners friendly, but one rule is that everything that is not explicitely forbidden is allowed, and few things are forbidden. A mutable type is mutable, full stop. If an API returns an internal mutable object, it implicitely allows the user of the API to modify that object.

That being said, it may or not be a problem. It is often enough to document that modifying the object is unsupported and may lead to unexpected behaviour.

It is often more Pythonic than trying to prevent wrong operations from the user of the API. After all, monkey patching is allowed, as is using any so called *private* members of a class, provided you can guess their name.